# Append query suggestion to Search Box from a third party Source in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

Is there a way to add additional items to the default query suggestions provided in the search box as a user types. I need to fetch suggestion items from a query template endpoint and add the returned items to the default query suggestions provided by the search box control in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Does the basic [query suggestion text file import method](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-query-suggestions-in-SharePoint-search-9ef0f859-3b92-41e9-b393-cb43d6094c7b) meet your requirements?

1. Sign in to the Office 365 Admin Center as a search administrator.Choose Admin > SharePoint > search > Query Suggestion Settings.
2. Open a text editor of your choice, and enter a list of terms that you want the system to always suggest to users. Only add one term per line to the text file, and don't mix languages in the text file.
3. Save the text file to a location that’s accessible from SharePoint Online. To import a list of query suggestions to SharePoint search, go to Always suggest phrases > Import from text file. When you import query suggestions, any existing ones will be overwritten.
4. Browse to the file that you want to import.
5. Go to Language for suggestion phrases, and select the processing language of your query suggestions. It should match the language of the terms in the text file.
6. Choose Save Settings.

Comment: Actually no, the list of suggestions will be fetched from a source that dynamically generates the list. The text file approach is static which is what I am not look for. Thanks.